# How Do I Format Text Like In The Linked Photo?

Tags: java

I have a floorplan type program that allows the user to drag and drop items onto the plan (haven't got the drag and drop working yet).  Each item has an associated labor cost and price that is stored in the object class for each item.

When the user clicks on the Get Estimate button I have a new window that pops up as in the following image.

[image: http://img5.imageshack.us/img5/5439/2wei.jpg]

I then want to try and format the text as in the image shown.  I have the window working with a JScrollPane and the buttons.  I assume when I get the items working that I will pass a reference to my array of items so that I can call item.getPrice() to get each item's cost and then display it as in the image.

What I would like to know is, what is the best way to format and display the data as shown with tabbed columns using the dynamic data?

Thanks!

Comment: You could use a `JEditorPane` and HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the string passed to a `JLabel` starts and ends with `<html>` and `</html>`, it will be interpreted as HTML.

So given the rather complex layout and style elements such as header separated with a horizontal line etc., and assuming that the table, once the window has been created, is static, the easiest way might be to use a single `JLabel` and format the text as an HTML table.

Comment: Thanks for the help, both of you.  I was thinking about both of these ideas but I wasn't sure.  I thought of a JLabel but I didn't know how hard it would be to format it.  I will look into using the HTML elements with it as I have some experience working with HTML.

Comment: How would I add variable data to the HTML?  Would I just do something like this?

"HTML code here" + item.getName() + "More HTML" + item.getPrice()

Comment: @KrisPurdy That's probably the easiest way. Alternatively, you could use String.format to insert the lines for the individual items. Might be a bit clearer.